# Variable assignment using eval

Tags: ruby, variables

Assigning a instance variable using eval works fine whereas the other doesn't.  Trying to understand whats happening here. Any help is appreciated.

```
>> var = "a value"
=> "a value"

>> @v
=> nil

>> eval "@v = var"
=> "a value"

>> @v
=> "a value"

>> eval "var_new = var"
=> "a value"

>> var_new
NameError: undefined local variable or method `var_new' for main:Object
        from (irb):7
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `eval` creates a new scope and `var_new` is *local* to that scope.

Comment: whereas `@v` is an instance variable of the containing object (inside `irb` that's an instance of `Object` - at least it is in 1.8.7), so it can be accessed from eval, and remains afterwards due to being scoped to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do kind of *introspection* as below :

```
var = "a value"
eval "var_new = var,defined?(var_new)" #=> ["a value", "local-variable"]
defined?(var_new) #=>nil
defined?(var) #=>"local-variable"
defined?(temp) #=>nil
```

You can see **var_new** is known to only inside the `eval`. Outside of `eval` **temp** and **var_new** both are same.

Answer (score 3):

`eval` simply has its own scope. You can access variables that were defined before but you will not get access to variables that are defined inside `eval`.

Scoping-wise, your example is similar to:

```
var = "a value"

1.times do # create new scope
  new_var = var
end

new_var
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_var' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 3):

eval creates its own scope:

```
>> i = 1; local_variables.count
=> 2
>> eval "j = 1; local_variables.count"
=> 3
>> local_variables.count
=> 2
```

Comment: does that mean instance variables are not in eval's own scope (local scope)?

Comment: instance variables are still around, and they're still in the context of the object. See the above tests, by replacing `i` and `j` by `@i` and `@j`, and `local_variables` with `instance_variables`. You'll end up incrementing the number of instance_variables as expected.